# Adding noise to a path in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path

Is it possible to add some (controllable amount of) noise to a path with Inkscape? When creating a fictional map, I would like to add rivers with the bezier tool, drawing the general shape, and then add some noise to make it look more realistic.

I have had a look at the different filters and effects, and no one seems appropriate (but I might have overlooked the right one).

Comment: Have you tried to convert the path into a shape and then add a filter like this: Filters->distort->Torn edges?

Answer (score 13):

In case you still need to know or someone else needs to know. There is a tool in `Extensions > Modify Path > Fractalize`. It can make a map in 5 minutes(ish)

1. Create your ground formation
2. Select all the land masses and go to `Extensions > Modify Path > Add Nodes` (not too many, they will help keep the the land formation) I just used it to make the nodes about the same distance apart so that one side is not a higher resolution.
3. With the land masses selected, go to `Extensions > Modify Path > Fractalize`.

   I would recommend using layers for map details like rivers, rocks and trees. Go to `Layers > Layers` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

   In the right side of the screen the layers should popup, add one, and use it.
4. Draw the bodies of water
5. Then Add Nodes and Fractal a little.
6. Then adjust the rivers to make sure they line up, and Fractal again.

Add some color and some details and you got it!

[image]